# Delphi: How to lock "Socket.Write" and unlock?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I have several clients, who writes to one socket (not port), when they write together, I receive the garbage, all data from all clients are merged.

all clients are in the same program in Threads.

I need to lock write()

```
ASocket.Connection.Socket.LOCK; // need to be thread safe
ASocket.Connection.Socket.Write(buf);
ASocket.Connection.Socket.UNLOCK; // need to be thread safe
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Delphi 2010, Indy 10, Win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TCriticalSection` (`SyncObjs` unit): put the `Write` between `Enter` and `Leave`:

```
CriticalSection.Enter;
try
  ASocket.Connection.Socket.Write(buf);
finally
  CriticalSection.Leave;
end;
```

The methods `Acquire` and `Release` do the same ([doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Using_Critical_Sections)). Important: if you write to the socket at multiple points of your code, you must use the same object (the one I called `CriticalSection` in the above example).

Comment: CriticalSection variable must be global ? And I need to .Create(); first somewhere once?

Comment: Sure. You have to declare `CriticalSection` as a `TCriticalSection`, and create it with `CriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;` and release it with `CriticalSection.Free;` after you finished using the socket and the lock is not needed anymore.

Comment: I would make the CS be a member of whatever class you are using for `ASocket`, that way you can have per-connection locks, eg: `ASocket.Lock.Enter; ...`.  But yes, you do ned to `Create()` and `Free()` the CS.

Comment: Actually, it does not have to be global, it can also be a member of a class. It depends on the overall structure of your code. If it's a simple console application, then yes, you can declare it in the global `var` section.

Comment: The CS should be created when the writeable socket is created - store it in whatever socket context is used.  You could maybe override write() to acquire/release it?